# How does WCF wrap xml body messages?

Tags: interop, wcf

I'm running into a problem getting my WCF service to work with other clients.

The ServiceContract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "/calculation/{accountNumber}")]
  string RunCalculations(string returnInformation, string accountNumber);
}
```

I wrote a simple client to make sure that everything was working, and when I pass in the xml I want, everything works swimmingly.

The problem is that the service exists to expose an interface our product to a third party vendor, who's developing a web interface in php.  When he tries to issue the request, he gets a 400 Bad Request error, which, looking through the trace, is caused when WCF tries to parse his xml.

The error message I get is:

```
Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'BusinessTaxReturn' and root namespace '' (for operation 'RunCalculations' and contract ('IMyService',  'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. 
Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.
```

I assume that WCF is wrapping the message that my client sends, and then attempting to unwrap it when the service recieves the message.  This leaves me with two questions:

1. What does WCF wrap XML messages with?
2. What is the best way to resolve this problem?  Should I just have the client wrap their message, or should I really be trying to use a DataContract?

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out, use a HTTP Debugging Proxy like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to spy on the messages your WCF client sends to the WCF server, and compare these to the messages sent by the PHP app.